# Python post requests - Content Type being removed from headers

Tags: python, post, header, request, python-requests

I am having an issue with python post request seemingly clearing the Content-Type header when posting.

I am using the same code elsewhere with success. Any ideas/pointers what would potentially cause the loss of the header?

Thanks

Adam

Sample of the code I am using:

```
reqsession.headers.update({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
print(reqsession.headers)
response = reqsession.post(response.url, data=data, headers = reqsession.headers)
print(response.request.headers)
```

Comment: i don't know how to word it, but the response headers should not be related to those you sent.

Comment: I believe response.request.headers will be the headers from my request, whereas response.headers would be the response headers. I believe you may have mistaken what I am printing for the latter.

Comment: yes i was. my bad. but i can't reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I think it's when your request gets redirected.

For me, I was using `http` instead of `https` and it was auto-redirecting, and making the "request" be a GET instead of a POST.